# Selenium i can't click button python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm try many method but not work U have any solution?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-solid-primary btn--l _3Kiuzg" aria-disabled="false">buy</button>
```

My code and Error

```py
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn-solid-primary").click()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

i can try

- find_elements_by_class_name

not work

```py
browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-solid-primary btn--l _3Kiuzg")
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project-Program\selenium\test3.py", line 11, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_class_name("btn btn-solid-primary btn--l _3Kiuzg")
  File "D:\Project-Program\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "D:\Project-Program\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\Project-Program\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Project-Program\selenium\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-solid-primary btn--l _3Kiuzg"}
```

Comment: the errors are self explanatory . In first case there is list object when you use `find_elements`,if you are using `find_element` it is saying not found..either use `sleep` or default objects within selenium so that all web elements are loaded

Comment: browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-solid-primary.btn--l").click() try this out. You want to use find_element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ans - Change elements to element in the below code.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn-solid-primary").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, I assume, you're parsing Instagram. It uses dynamic classes (In your case, `_3Kiuzg`), that change after page reload. So ensure, you're not looking for element by it. Function `find_element_by_class_name` is not taking many classes, so, if you want such, you should use `find_element_by_css_selector`, and selector `.class_1.class_2.etc`